# Azure email poller stuck in "InProgress"

Tags: python, azure, email, email-attachments, azure-communication-services

I'm using `azure-communication-email` python package to send an email from a Databricks cluster. The script worked fine with older release but they've recently rolled out the new version (version 1.0.0b2 from 03/07/23) which uses a different composing style.

```
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient
email_client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(comm_connection_string)
display_name = make_user_display_name(username)
message = {
    "content": {
        "subject": f"Subject",
        "plainText": f"email body here",
    },
        "recipients": {
            "to": [
                {
                    "address": username,
                    "displayName": display_name
                }
            ]
},
    "senderAddress": "DoNotReply@azurecomm.net",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "name":save_name,
            "contentType": "txt",
            "contentInBase64": file_bytes_b64.decode()
        }
    ]
}
poller = email_client.begin_send(message)
result = poller.result()
```

The script never finishes because `poller` gets stuck in "InProgress" state. How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: does this happen all the time or only sometimes after sending multiple emails?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> The script never finishes because `poller` gets stuck in "InProgress" state. How do I go about debugging this?

The `poller.result()` never returns, it is likely that the email-sending process is still in progress, and you may need to wait for the operation to complete and also check the recipient's mail is in correct.

I used the below code to send a mail with attachments and it executed successfully by sending a mail to recipients in the data bricks cluster.

**Code:**

```
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient
import base64

with open("/dbfs/FileStore/filename.txt", "r") as file:
    file_contents = file.read()

file_bytes_b64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(file_contents, 'utf-8'))

comm_connection_string="Your connection string"
email_client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(comm_connection_string)
message = {
    "content": {
        "subject": "This is the subject",
        "plainText": "This is the body",
        "html": "<html><h1>This is the body</h1></html>"
    },
        "recipients": {
            "to": [
                {
                    "address": "youremail@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "venkat"
                }
            ]
},
    "senderAddress": "DoNotReply@<Your domain>.azurecomm.net",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "name": "attachment.txt",
            "contentType": "text/plain",
            "contentInBase64": file_bytes_b64.decode()
        }
    ]
}
poller = email_client.begin_send(message)
result = poller.result()

print("Email is send to Recipient Sucessfully")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Mail:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure-communication-email · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/azure-communication-email/1.0.0b2/)